# Are there “server-side comments” in JSF / Seam / RichFaces?

Tags: jsf, comments, seam, richfaces, facelets

With the JSF/Seam/RichFaces stack, is there a way to mark up comments (on XHTML pages) so that they will *not* be included in the HTML output? I.e., something like JSP's `<%-- comments --%>`, as opposed to normal `<!-- comments -->`.

I heard that `facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS` context-param migth do this for normal HTML comments, but is there any other option? (After all, there might be some comments that you *want* included in the page output and some that you don't.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found an answer in [a thread on the JSF for nonbelievers forum of IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14289124):

```
<ui:remove><!--
    <tags you want to remove/>
--></ui:remove>
```

See [the official Facelets documentation of ui:remove](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#template-remove) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this works! (For the record, if using IntelliJ IDEA, one could as well leave out the `<!-- -->` comments inside `<ui:remove>`, as IDEA won't show the contents as commented.)

Comment: Link now seems to be: https://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#template-remove (no more dev in the URL?)

Answer (score 6):

Use the `facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS` context-param. You won't need comments in the generated pages. They are not meant to be human-readable anyway.

Comment: "They are not meant to be human-readable anyway" <-- reason #293 why we front end dev's hate JSF pages. ;)